# How to reconnect to Google Home devices after signing out?

Tags: google-home, nest-cam, nest

My wife was concerned that she had a virus on her PC.  Out of an abundance of caution,  she used the "sign out of all my devices" option in Google Home on her laptop.

The devices (Nest thermostat, Nest outdoor camera) naturally also disappeared from the Google Home app on her phone and tablet.

We've since taken care of the virus issue.  So now the question is, how do we re-add the devices back to our Google Home app?  Is there an easy way to do it?  Or are we starting from square one here?

We tried adding the thermostat as a new device, but after scanning the QR code on the back and choosing which wires it has, it put us in an endless loop of "Something went wrong.  Could not save your changes", over and over.

We also tried adding the camera as a new device, but we were unable to find a QR code sticker anywhere on it.  (I'm guessing the installation guy gave the sticker to us and told us to keep it somewhere safe, but that was a long time ago and I have no idea where that paperwork is...)

Is there an easy way out of this mess?  Is there an easy way to re-add the devices we previously had in the app?